# How have I got a badge with only part of the requirements?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that I have the deputy badge, which is 80 helpful flags, yet in my profile it says I've only made 77. So where have I got the extra flags from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comment flags are counted as well, and you have 2 comment flags. I show you having 78 helpful flags, and 2 comment flags.